# Android App crashes in the release build due to NullPointerException when setting minifyEnabled to true and shrinkResources to true

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, preferenceactivity

when setting  `minifyEnabled`  to `true` causes `nullpointerException`
when I set `minifyEnabled` to `false` the problem gone

but I want to set `minifyEnabled` to `true` and `shrinkResources` to `true` to keep my app size small and delete unused classes

also try to use those lines in the `ProGuard-rules.txt` and the problem not solved

Code

```
Preference appearance = findPreference(AppearanceSettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            appearance.setOnPreferenceClickListener(prefClickListener);

Preference behavior = findPreference(BehaviorSettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            behavior.setOnPreferenceClickListener(prefClickListener);

Preference storage = findPreference(StorageSettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            storage.setOnPreferenceClickListener(prefClickListener);

Preference browser = findPreference(BrowserSettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            browser.setOnPreferenceClickListener(prefClickListener);

Preference limitations = findPreference(LimitationsSettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            limitations.setOnPreferenceClickListener(prefClickListener);
```

Config

```
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.** { *; }

-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }

-keep class SettingsFragment.** { *; }
-keep class com.mix.downloader.model.* { *; }
-keepattributes Annotation,Signature
```

Above is what I have tried, still issue is not resolved.

Exception reported

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mix.downloader, PID: 31333
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.preference.Preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(androidx.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceClickListener)' on a null object reference**
at com.mix.downloader.ui.settings.SettingsFragment.onViewCreated(SettingsFragment.java:115)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:5)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:262)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:117)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:31)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:57)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:10)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:12)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:5)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:21)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:1)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8231)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3845)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2309)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8587)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

Comment: setOnPreferenceClickListener(androidx.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceClickListener), you are calling this somewhere in your code, can you share that code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also `-keep` all your `SettingsFragment` classes since you're using `Class.class.getSimpleName()` which will be affected by Proguard/R8.
Guessing from your stacktrace, it will look something like this:

`-keep class com.mix.downloader.ui.settings.** { ; }`